# Using +[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:completion:], the completion is not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, magicalrecord, magicalrecord-2.2

When I call `saveWithBlock:completion:` it actually saves the data but doesn't call the completion Block. Is there a bug, or am I using this method the wrong way?

I use MagicalRecord 2.2 from CocoaPods. I've tried to downgrade to 2.1 with no luck -- the problem remains.

```
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithInMemoryStore];
[MagicalRecord setDefaultModelNamed:@"Model.momd"];

[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    TestUser *test = [TestUser MR_createInContext:localContext];
    test.name = @"Lweek";
} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Yeah");
}];
```

This outputs nothing. The completion Block is not triggered, although the data are saved properly.

Comment: The same problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872105/magicalrecord-completion-block-is-not-called-under-test-target