# MagicalRecord completion block is not called under test target

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, magicalrecord

```
MagicalRecord.saveWithBlock({ context in

        if let items = dictionary["items"] as? Array<NSDictionary> {
            for itemInfo in items {
                DBItem.findOrUpdateItemWithDictionary(itemInfo, inContext: context)
            }
        }
        //is called
        if let sets = dictionary["item_sets"] as? Array<NSDictionary> {
            for setInfo in sets {
                DBSet.findOrUpdateSetWithDictionary(setInfo, inContext: context)
            }
        }

        }, completion: { finished, error in

        completionBlock(error) //is not called
})
```

This is how I setup my core data stack:

```
MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStackWithInMemoryStore()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `saveWithBlock:` method is executed asynchronously. The test might be finished before calling completion block though I do not know how is your test code.

https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/c7b14f658b4fca32f8d33f8f76160203053ce4b9/MagicalRecord/Core/MagicalRecord%2BActions.m#L14-L35

Could you try to change the `saveWithBlock:` method to `saveWithBlockAndWait:`? It is executed syncronously. Or wait to execute asynchronous call with `XCTestExpectation`?